# Palindromic vector sequential

Tags: c++

So I need in c++ program to determinate the longest sequential palindromic. Here is an example v=(3,4,**1,5,2,5,1**,8,9,6) to show me 5 and to remember the position of first 1 and last 1 I this case .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int v[100],n,i,j,max=0,maxi=0,maxj=0,cni,cnj,l;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>v[i];
    cnj=n-1;
    cni=0;
    while(j!=0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            if(v[i]==v[j])
            {
                l=j-i;
                if(max<j-i)
                {
                    max=j-i;
                    maxi=i;
                    maxj=j;
                }
                j--;
            }
            else
                j=cnj;
        }
        j--;
        cnj=j;
    }
    while(i!=n-1)
    {
        for(j=n;j>i;j--)
        {
            if(v[i]==v[j])
            {
                if(max<j-i)
                {
                    max=j-i;
                    maxi=i;
                    maxj=j;
                }
                i++;
            }
            else
                i=cni;
        }
        i++;
        cni=i;
    }
    cout<<maxi<<"  "<<maxj;

    return 0;
}
```

When i run it codeblocks it stops working

Comment: I am thinking at something like this..(the code is in the question).

Comment: @Michael And how it doesn't work specifically?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well it stops working. i uploaded all the code.

Comment: @Raindrop7 You can check my attempt.

Comment: @Michael The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ at least i am going in the right way with the program ?

Comment: @Michael It's your turn to check that. Do all the variables and code flows behave in the way you expect them to do?

Comment: Right out of the gate: `..\main.cpp(18): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'j' used`

Comment: @lakeweb ops. Thanks for that the program is working now.

Comment: what if `n` is greater than `100`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

- palindrome is probable if only and if there are two values are equal begin and and
- if we found the begin and the end it is not a palindrome yet but we exclude all the values out of this interval and go on check the palindrome interval values 2 by two and if two value are not equal then it is not a palindrome so we break and go back search again for anther two equal values (begin and end of palindrome).

this code will check for all palindromes and sub-palindromes (palindrome inside another one) however if you want only one palindrome then uncomment out break below:

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {   

        int begIndex = -1, endIndex = -1; // index of begin and end of palindrome if found then they will be set to not -1
        int size; // size of array
        bool IsPalindrome = false; // initialize to flase

        int array[] = {3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 5, 1, 8, 9, 6, 9, 8};
        size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); // getting number of elements of array

        for(int i(0); i < size; i++)
        {// for 1
            for(int j(size - 1); j > i; j--) // j begins from the end -1 and stop if it is equal or less than i to ensure not reading out of palindrome interval
            {// for 2
                if(array[i] == array[j]) // comparing if ok set begin and end indexes of palindrome
                {
                    IsPalindrome = true; // if ok then go to the next test
                    begIndex = i; // only save begin and end indexes of palindrome
                    endIndex = j;

                    // checking two by two and any not equal two values will make it non-palindrome and breaks the inner loop and go back again to check
                    for(int k(begIndex), l(endIndex); k < endIndex; k++, l--)
                    {
                        if(array[k] != array[l]) // last check proves it a palindrome so if two elements are not equal here then it's not palindrome break and go back checking again
                        {
                            IsPalindrome = false;
                            begIndex = endIndex = -1; // reset for checking again
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // note the check is inside second loop to continue checking if next test proves it's not a palindrome
            }// ~for 2

           // now if the last check doesn't prove that it is not a palindrome we print our palindrome:
            if(IsPalindrome)
            {
                for(int m(begIndex); m <= endIndex; m++)
                {
                    std::cout << array[m] << ", ";
                }
                IsPalindrome = false;
                begIndex = endIndex = -1;
               // break; // if you want one palindrome then uncomment break otherwise you'll get all palindomes from biggest to smallest 
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }

        }// ~for 1

        std::cout << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```